# .Net user control cause an unexpected postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

Hi I am a user control to trigger ActiveStepIndex change of a wizard on the main aspx page.

The wizard control is inside the update panel.So if I trigger ActiveStepIndex from the aspx page, then the postback will only happen within the update panel. However if I trigger ActiveStepIndex from the user control, then the postback will happen in the whole page.

Codes from user control:

```
Wizard mainWizard = Parent.FindControl("wizBlindOrder") as Wizard;
mainWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 2;
```

I don't want the whole page to be refreshed (postback) when I trigger ActiveStepIndex from the user control, can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

actually I found the answer, I just use trigger inside the update panel, and refer to the user control id:

```
<Triggers>
<asp:ASyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="..."/>
</Triggers>
```